# Issues with tabbing between Filter Fields with Horizontal scrolling - scrolling out of sync

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a wide grid with horizontal scrolling, with 2 frozen columns. It is very wide (over 20 columns), so the horizontal scrolling is always needed.

We are using the Filter Row option to allow the user to filter. Works well, but if the user tabs between the filter fields, an issue arises. If the user tabs to a hidden field (hidden as in having to scroll to see it), then the header will scroll to accomodate, but the body will not. Likewise, if the user is scrolled all the way to the right and tabs out of the last frozen column, the scrolling again gets out of sync.

See the following Dojo example to experience the issue yourself.​

http://dojo.telerik.com/iNONA/2

If anyone has any clue as to how to fix this issue, I'd appreciate it very much!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem, just without angluar implementation. For me the jQuery scrollLeft() method solved the problem, see ([Grid data isn't align with Grid header when tabbing through header columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513661/grid-data-isnt-align-with-grid-header-when-tabbing-through-header-columns/42528367#42528367)).

```
$("#example .k-grid-content").scrollLeft($("#example .k-grid-header-wrap").scrollLeft())
```

With that line of code I got it working in the developer console of your Dojo example to adjust the grid content to the position of the header. But the scroll event, as I implemented it on my problem, didn't work on your example. Maybe this helps you and you can adjust it with the scroll event in angular.